# Why my program runs fast when I make a call to System.nanoTime() outside the System.out.println statement?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, system

My program runs 30000ns faster with this code:

```
long t = System.nanoTime();
...
long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println("Time: " + (t2 - t));
```

Than with this other:

```
long t = System.nanoTime();
...
System.out.println("Time: " + (System.nanoTime() - t));
```

In the first one, I even make another variable, why is it faster then?

Comment: Look at [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one creates a new StringBuilder and appends a String to it before taking the timings.  The first one takes the timing before doing this extra work.

The second one is equivalent to

```
System.out.println(new StringBuilder().append("Time: ")
                   .append(System.nanoTime() - t).toString());
```

or

```
StringBuildler sb = new StringBuilder().append("Time: "); // included in timing
long time = System.nanoTime() - t;
System.out.println(sb.append(time).toString());
```

BTW Just performing an output to the console can disturb very short tasks and make them slower. I suggest you run the test many times, ignore the first 20K as warm up and  print a summary of the results at the end.

Comment: I was doing the important task in the "..." part. I will keep it in mind. Thanks!